# Cakephp 3 save related data in foreach

Tags: foreach, cakephp-3.0

How exactly use `$item = $this->Items->newEntity();` to save data from `$this->request->data` in foreach loop.

```
 $item = $this->Items->newEntity();
 foreach ($array as $item) {

        //added for sake of answer
        $item = $this->Items->newEntity();
        $this->request->data['objects']['_ids'][] = $item['object_id'];
        $this->Items->patchEntity($item, $this->request->data);
        $this->Items->save($item); 
        //added
        unset($this->request->data['object']['_ids']);

        }
```

When `newEntity()` is outside of foreach, then there is one `item.id` and correct number of object.ids but in relationship to the same `item.id`. When I set `newEntity()` to be inside of the foreach loop, then I have correct number of `item.ids`, but incorrect numbers of `object.id` in the table `items_object` (exceeding the number from the array).

the answer:

Put `newEntity()` inside foreach and `unset($this->request->data['object']['_ids']);` at the end. It seems to producing correct entries.

Comment: You need to use `Associated` when doing patch entity.

Comment: Something looks very wrong about your "solution": you're using `$item` in the `foreach`, but then immediately overwriting it with the result of the `newEntity` call. These obviously need to be different variables.